# find_element_by_xpath works fine in one function, but not in the next one - nonetype error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to figure out why essentially the same line of code works in one function, but not in another.

I have three files as shown below.

My issue is that it runs default_login() fine and has no issue with the find_element_by_xpath line, but then fails to run log_out() and bombs out at the find_element_by_xpath line with the following error: -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

I can run this same line independently in a file with no functions defined and it finds the element without issue.

I also get the same (similar) error when it runs the tearDown() line self.driver.quit(): -

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'quit'
```

If anybody could tell me why it is failing like this I would appreciate it greatly. I'm having all sorts of issues like this and am starting to wonder whether I have something configured wrong somewhere...

Project files: -

initialisation.py

```
from selenium import webdriver


def start_webdriver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\TEMP\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver


def start_browser(driver):
    driver.get("https://myURL")
    return driver
```

login.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


def default_login(driver):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    login_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'login')]")
    login_link.click()

    username_text_field = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email")))
    password_text_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

    username_text_field.send_keys("username")
    password_text_field.send_keys("password")

    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn save btn-primary']")
    login_button.click()


def log_out(driver):
    new_project = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='my-projects-table']/tbody/tr/td[3]")
    new_project.click()
    logout_user = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-toggle")
    logout_user.click()
    logout_sign_out = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'logout')]")
    logout_sign_out.click()
    print("logged out")
```

just_a_test.py

```
import unittest
from Common import initialisation, login


class RegisterPatientsTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = initialisation.start_webdriver()
        self.driver = initialisation.start_browser(self.driver)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_another_quick_test(self):
        self.driver = login.default_login(self.driver)
        self.driver = login.log_out(self.driver)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function with no `return` statement is essentially a function with `return None`. Your function `login.default_login()` has no `return` statement, thus returning a `None`. And then `self.driver` is assigned to `None`:

```
self.driver = login.default_login(self.driver)
```

Just add `return driver` to `login.default_login()` and `login.log_out()` functions to fix both errors.

Comment: Thanks Hoefling, this was exactly what I needed! :)